# Como redirecionar url com interrogação com o .htaccess?

Tags: apache, htaccess

Estou com o seguinte problema, preciso redirecionar a seguinte url:

```
site/nossos-socios.php?termo=teste
```

para

```
site/nossos-socios/?q=teste
```

Eu preciso que tenha a interrogação antes do q=, tentei utilizar o escape com a interrogação, porém não funciona.

Segue o meu .htaccess abaixo, ele redireciona apenas para **`nossos-socios/q=aço`**:

```
RewriteRule ^nossos-socios/q\=([^/.]+)?$ nossos-socios.php?termo=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Da uma olhada [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18543913/5429980). Provavelmente vc terá que usar o `%{QUERY_STRING}` como citado na resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achei a solução, é necessário utilizar a `RewriteCond` com uma query string:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(nossos-socios)/?$ $1.php?termo=%1 [NC,L]
```